# Assign 2 char to an int

Tags: c++, char, int, ascii

I am trying to understand the outcome of this code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 'dd';
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is 25700. How the compiler get this number?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ascii code for `'d'` is 0x64. The literal `'dd'` was represented as 0x6464 by your compiler, which is 25700 when written in decimal notation.

Comment: You should note in the answer that this is no universal rule. Each compiler is free to interpret multi-character `''` literals however it wants.

Comment: Noted. I was just explaining how in the OP's particular case the characters  relate to the number 25700.

Comment: So I can not know in advance what value will assume for sure (if 25700 or others in others compiler) right?

Comment: @andre3312 If you want to guarantee a particular value, you have to calculate it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

`'dd'` is a multi-character literal, its type is `int` and its value is implementation-defined.

In many implementations, the value is calculated as `256 * 'd' + 'd'`, which is `25700`.

---

From C++11 §2.13.2 Character literals

> ... An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter literal. A multicharacter literal has type `int` and implementation-defined value.

Answer (score 0):

`'dd'` was implicitly converted to `int` value by the statement `int a='dd';`