# assigning more than one character in char

Tags: c, char

Why this program gives output `'y'`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy';
    printf("%c",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

[Code at ideone](http://ideone.com/vtuMBK)

Comment: Remember that the type of a single-quoted character constant is `int`, but you're assigning it to a `char`, so it has to be truncated to a single character.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384731/multibyte-integers-variables-in-c/13384799#13384799

Comment: Twin question in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101247/assign-2-char-to-an-int

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a multi-character literal.

> An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a
>   multicharacter literal . A multicharacter literal has type int and
>   **implementation-deﬁned value**.

Also from 6.4.4.4/10 in C11 specs

> An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer
>   character constant containing a single character that maps to a
>   single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the
>   representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. The
>   value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character (e.g., **'ab'**), or containing a character or escape sequence
>   that does not map to a **single-byte execution character**, is
>   **implementation-defined**. If an integer character constant contains a
>   single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results
>   when an object with type char whose value is that of the single
>   character or escape sequence is converted to type int.

So the line `char ch = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy'` on your system (assuming 4 byte int) possibly compiles to:

```
char ch = 0x76777879;  // SOME int value (may be different, but documented in the compiler documents)
```

`ch` will be assigned `'abcdef...y'` [which **may be** equivalent to](http://ideone.com/SfhNNO) `(int)0x616263646566...79` in ascii encoding and overflows an integer. This is the reason why `gcc` generates the following warning:

> *multicharlit.c: In function ‘main’:
>  multicharlit.c:4:13: warning:
>   character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
>
>   multicharlit.c:4:5: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
>   [-Woverflow]*

It appears on your system, least significant 8 bits are used to assign to `ch`. Because your character literal is constant, this most possibly happens at compile time: (For example following happens when I compile with `gcc`)

```
$ cat multicharlit.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy';
    printf("%c",ch);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -O2 -fdump-tree-optimized multicharlit.c 
$ cat multicharlit.c.143t.optimized 

;; Function main (main) (executed once)

main ()
{
<bb 2>:
  __builtin_putchar (121);
  return 0;

}
```

---

Also stealing some goodness from [unwind's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335472/assigning-more-than-one-character-in-char#comment50655643_31335472)

> Remember that the type of a single-quoted character constant is `int`,
>   but you're assigning it to a `char`, so it has to be truncated to a
>   single character.

Type of `'a'` for example is `int` in `C`. (Not to be confused with `'a'` in `C++` which is a char. On the other hand type of `'ab'` is `int` in **both** `C` and `C++`.)

Now when you assign this `int` type to a `char` type and value is more than that can be represented by a `char`, then some squeezing needs to be done to fit the result into less wider type `char` and the actual result is implementation-defined.

Comment: @LoveToCode: The compiler must document the implementation-defined behaviour, and presumably, the compiler you're using places the last character in the multi-character constant into the character value.  It could have been the first, or fourth, or any other character that the implementation chose — it merely has to document what it chose to do (and then it should also do it).

Answer (score 0):

If you intended to print out *abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy*, then you should have stored it into a string variable instead of a char one (char ch[50] = char abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy;).

String variables can hold *more than one character*, where as a char variable is for holding one character.