# Can I assign 2 values into a char variable?

Tags: java, capitalization

I'm wondering if I can compare a char with 2 values? I'm trying to make a loop that will repeat until some variable is equal to either `A`, `a`, `B`, `b`, `C`, or `c`.
Is there any way to ignore the capitalization?

I tried the following code:

```
 final char choiceA = 'a'|'A';
 final char choiceB = 'b'|'B';
 final char choiceC = 'c'|'C';
```

When I tried it it works only when I put `a`, `b` or `c`. If I put a capital letter the loop keeps going on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335472/assigning-more-than-one-character-in-char similar with this

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223176/how-to-compare-character-ignoring-case-in-primitive-types :)

Comment: XY problem, I fixed the question to highlight OPs expectations instead of his attempted solution.

Comment: Closely related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/234591

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A character cannot be both lowercase and uppercase, but you **can** ignore case when you compare characters (by converting your input to upper/lower case). E.g.:

```
char c = Character.toLowerCase(choice);
switch (c) {
     case 'a':
       // choice is either 'a' or 'A'
     case 'b':
       // choice is either 'b' or 'B'
     case 'c':
       // choice is either 'c' or 'C'
}
```

Comment: what is  the meaning of the // ... a? If I do toUpperCase wouldnt it ignore the lower case a and only accept A?

Comment: @JohnJaure see the edited content now. FWIW, this is a typical case for `switch`; also, AFAIR, the usual idiom is to convert to lowercase, not uppercase

Comment: The "//" is a comment.  Can I suggest that you should be do a Java tutorial before you start trying to write code?  It will save you a lot of hair-tearing.   It is best to learn the capabilities of the Java language rather than guess them by experimenting with the syntax.